# How can I create a tag with Github for Mac?

Tags: mac, github

GitHub for Mac OS X is cool software. I can do a lot of cool things with it (history, branches, etc) - but I don't know how to create tags. Can I do this with the GUI?

#### GitHub for Mac

[image]

Comment: This should be possible now (2020). See [my edited answer](https://superuser.com/a/308682/141) below.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Both in [their announcement](https://github.com/blog/878-announcing-github-for-mac) and in the [help section](http://mac.github.com/), this (tag) doesn't seem to be available (at the time of the writing of this answer).

That means GitHub for Mac doesn't manage yet the tags namespace (refs/tags), and that you need to tag manually, and then `git push --tags` to GitHub also manually.

---

Nine years later, May 2020: "[Create and push tags in the latest GitHub Desktop 2.5 release](https://github.blog/2020-05-12-create-and-push-tags-in-the-latest-github-desktop-2-5-release/)"

> With today’s 2.5 release, you can create and view your tags directly from GitHub Desktop.
>
> Now when you push to GitHub.com, any tags created in Desktop are automatically included. GitHub Desktop also notifies you when you’ve created tags but haven’t yet pushed them, so you don’t forget to share your latest tag with the rest of the team.

[image: https://i1.wp.com/user-images.githubusercontent.com/10404068/81434697-70277500-911b-11ea-9b30-d5da8a80a664.gif?ssl=1]